# JPanel is not sizing correctly

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to make a kind of strategy game, and I can't get the JPanel to fill the whole JFrame. I have looked on the forums, and none of the other posts about this have helped me. Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class FCG extends JPanel{
static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Fleet Commander Greg");
static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
static JLabel ship = new JLabel();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ship.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/Users/Alexander/workspace/Fleet Commander Greg/src/res/sprite_1.png"));
    ship.setBounds(32,32,0,0);
    panel.add(ship);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(1800,900);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.
- The Super Good Coder That Will Some Day Rule The Universe

EDIT:
Ok, so i got it working, (kinda) but there is still some scape between the top of the frame and the top of the image. Here is my main method:

```
stars.setIcon(new ImageIcon("/Users/Alexander/workspace/Destroy the World/res/stars_1.png"));
     stars.setBounds(0,0,400,500);
     panel.add(stars);
     frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
     frame.add(panel);
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setSize(400, 500);
     frame.setVisible(true);
```

I don't know why it's doing this, it should be working well from what I've seen.
Thank you - The Not Very Good Coder Who Will Never Take Over the Universe

Comment: I don't understand your question. You add a label containing an image to the frame. The label does take up all the space. However, the image will be painted at its actual size. That is the image is not automatically scaled to fill the size of the frame.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the JPanel to fill the whole JFrame, then give the Frame a

```
setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
```

(if you have only this JPanel). Also don't forget to use

```
getContentPane().add(panel);
```

If you have several other things on your Frame or your panel within the Frame is nested in some other stuff, then use GridLayout on that to maximize the size.

Comment: The default layout of a frame is a BorderLayout. When you add a component to the frame without specify a constraint the component goes to the CENTER. The CENTER will occupy all the available space of the frame. Stick with the BorderLayout. It gives you the option of add a toolbar to the frame or a status bar as well. No need to restrict the frame to a single component. Also, since JCK4 you no longer need to use getContentPane(). You can add the component directly to the frame and it will add it to the content pane for you.